# Navigation doesn't work when trying to GoBack to MainPage (Xamarin, Prism)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I have a HelpPage in my project that has a BackButton with this command on BaseViewModel:

```
DelegateCommand _goBack;
        public DelegateCommand GoBack => _goBack
            ?? (_goBack = new DelegateCommand(async () => await ExecuteGoBack()));

 private async Task ExecuteGoBack()
        {
            await NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
        }
```

When I am in my MainScreen and navigate to the HelpPage this BackButton doesn't work anymore. There is no error accused, it goes throught the method and just don't do anything. Also I have tried to put a button in the HelpPage to Navigate to mainScreen instead of going back, and doesn't work either. This the the way that I first navigate to my MainScreen:

```
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"/{App.GetMainPageName()}"));
```

And in the App.cs:

```
public static string GetMainPageName()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("App.cs: " + BluetoothModule.Instance.FirmwareVersion);
            switch (BluetoothModule.Instance.FirmwareVersion)
            {
                case FirmwareVersions.V1:
                    return nameof(MainPageV1);
                case FirmwareVersions.V2:
                    return nameof(MainPageV2V3);
                case FirmwareVersions.V3:
                    return nameof(MainScreen); 
                case FirmwareVersions.V4:
                    return nameof(MainPageV2V3);
                default:
                    return nameof(MainPageV2V3);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in [Prism doc Navigation Basics / section Navigating](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html#navigating).

See the explanation of "`Absolute`" vs "`Relative`" navigation.

The previous page is only pushed on stack when you use "Relative" syntax.

In your case, that would be:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(
        $"{App.GetMainPageName()}",   // <-- removed "/" at start of path.
        UriKind.Relative));   // <-- you are missing this parameter.
```

---

**UPDATE**

According to the comments, removing the "/" at start is sufficient to make it a relative URL; specifying `Relative` parameter is optional.

Comment: I guess, also the `/` should not be at the beginning of the path

Comment: @Haukinger - thanks, I missed that detail. Fixed.

Comment: in fact, that makes it an absolute url, without the leading slash, you can drop `UriKind.Relative`

Comment: The problem was when I navigate to HelpPage I was doing an Absolute Navigation. Just removing the "/"solved.